# Flex Spark Textinput different component width and inside text width

Tags: apache-flex, size, textinput, flex-spark

I am trying to change the length in pixels of the text displayed INSIDE a spark Textinput component.
On a mx Textinput I would have overridden updateDisplayList and modified textField width but I can't come up with a similar solution here.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom skin for your Spark TextInput.

It may look like this (a copy of the default TextInputSkin):

```
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" 
    alpha.disabledStates="0.5" blendMode="normal">

    <fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 

        [HostComponent("spark.components.TextInput")]
    ]]>
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            ...
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="disabled" stateGroups="disabledStates"/>
        <s:State name="normalWithPrompt"/>
        <s:State name="disabledWithPrompt" stateGroups="disabledStates"/>
    </s:states>

    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" id="border">
        <s:stroke>     
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Rect id="background" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="0xFFFFFF" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Rect left="1" top="1" right="1" height="1" id="shadow">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" alpha="0.12" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:RichEditableText id="textDisplay"
              verticalAlign="middle"
              widthInChars="10"
              left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" />

    <s:Label id="promptDisplay" maxDisplayedLines="1"
                verticalAlign="middle"
                mouseEnabled="false" mouseChildren="false"
                includeIn="normalWithPrompt,disabledWithPrompt" 
                includeInLayout="false"
                />
```

There you can see a RichEditableText named *textDisplay* - this is the actual text input field inside the TextInput. You can position it in the way you want.

Comment: I am not yet very familiar with spark components but looks like they are a lot easier to tune!
Thanks a lot this was very helpful ;)